# To learn Tripitaka to academic level

Tags: tipitaka, learning, university

Please recommend a place or university to learn Tipitaka in academic level.

Including

- Availability of visa
- Qualifications required
- Internationally acclaimed in someways
- Using English as a second language to study Tripitaka
- Requirement of ordained monk or can learn as a layperson
- Further studies after graduated, mastered or honored

Answer (score 1):

Following may be good academic institution to learn Buddhism:

- [The Buddhist and Pali University of Sri Lanka](http://www.bpu.ac.lk/)
- [The International Association of Theravāda Buddhist Universities](http://atbu.org/)
- [International Association of Buddhist Universities](http://www.iabu.org/)
- [Buddhist Universities and Colleges](http://www.4icu.org/religious/Buddhist.htm)
- [Buddhist universities and colleges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Buddhist_universities_and_colleges)
- [List of Buddhist universities and colleges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Buddhist_universities_and_colleges)
- [Buddhist universities and colleges in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_universities_and_colleges_in_the_United_States)